# Should I abbreviate variable and function names in a library?

Tags: c, coding-style, naming-conventions, naming

I am working on a C data structures library and I want my code to be clear, not having too much comments and still being readable, but I am struggling with naming.

1. Should I use `sinit()` and `linit()` or `stackInit()` and `listInit()` to differentiate Stack and List functions?
2. The variable holding a List should be `list_t *ls` or `list_t *list`?
3. The variable that holds the size of each piece of data in a structure should be `datasize` or `dataSize`?
4. Inside a structure I have a pointer to a function (given by the user) that would compare two elements, should it be `cmp` or `compare`?

I know all this questions are mostly the same, but I needed to make all cases in the code clear.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question that is not suitable for StackOverflow's Q&A format because there really is no right answer. Just make sure your function names can be understood at a glance, stick to one case style (e.g. camelCase vs snake_case), don't worry about commonly used abbreviations like `cmp` that can be easily understood, etc.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you don't even try replicating some of the the (IMO) weird names/naming styles in the C standard library (especially in `string.h` for some reason) (e.g. `strstr`, `strpbrk`, `alloca`, `strcspn` etc.) that would be very very hard to understand without googling the purpose of the function.

Comment: The reason for the C standard library function names is that in the past a compiler might only use 8 first characters of an identifier to distinguish between functions... but since medieval ages C has actually required that any implementation will consider at least *31* first characters.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: The required amount was never eight characters. It was six in the 1990 C standard and 31 in the 1999 C standard. I vaguely recall IBM operating system module names having some naming scheme to fit in the six-character limit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil 6? :D I stand corrected... [6 significant initial characters in an external identifier](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#2.2.4.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stackInit()` and `listInit()` are more readable thean `sinit()` and `linit()`.

The same way the declaration `list_t *list` is more readable than `list_t *ls`.

As for function names you are using the camel style then it is better when variable names differ from function names. So I would prefer to use `datasize` or `data_size` instead of `dataSize`.

`cmp` is a common used synonym for the word `compare` or `comparison`. There is such an assembler command for Intel processors. So you may use either `cmp` , `compare` or `comparison`.

Comment: Though if it is a short function with only one argument, `list_t *list` doesn't really convey any more information than `list_t *l`...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The name 'l' can be encountered somewhere else inside the code. So it will be difficult to determine what  it means and whether it is indeed 'l' and not '1'.

Comment: True, but fortunately outside Stack Overflow one usually has working syntax highlighting :D